# ATXMega ADC - What is bandgap reference and temperature?

Tags: adc, avr, atxmega

On my ATXMega128A1U, I am using ADCA to measure an input voltage (roughly ~1.70V) and I plan to use a VREF of 2.5V. I was reading the XMEGA manual, specifically for the REFCTRL register where I would set REFSEL to 010 for AREFA as seen below:

[image]

However I am a bit confused by what the bandgap and temperature bits are for as in I am not sure whether I need to enable them or not. I have seen some other projects set these bits but I was wondering what exactly does it do? What happens if I don't set these bits at all and use the ADC?

Edit: Link to XMEGA manual http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/doc8077.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **bandgap reference** provides an *internal* reference voltage of 1.1 V; you can then use it by setting REFSEL to 000. You don't need that, you want to use an *external* reference voltage, i.e. REFSEL 010 or 011. It doesn't matter whether you  enable it or not – as you're not using it. Turning on the bandgap will consume a little power, but typically not significantly much.

Many microcontrollers have a **temperature sensor** built-in. Bit 0 enables the one in your microcontroller. You *can* then use the ADC with a special ADC channel to measure what that sensor says. Unless you plan to use that sensor, it doesn't matter whether you turn it on. Again, turning it on will use a  little power.